# Flutter flutter_html package not work with api

Tags: html, css, flutter, webview, flutter-html

```dart
Html(
    data: """
    ${cubit.umrapages![cubit.currentPageIndex].content}
    """,
    extensions: [
       IframeHtmlExtension(),
    ],
    style: {
        "p.fancy": Style(
            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
            backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
            margin: Margins(
                left: Margin(50, Unit.px),
                right: Margin.auto()),
            width: Width(300, Unit.px),
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
    },
),
```

This is my Flutter code. When I pass a static HTML string it accepts it but can't convert the HTML code coming from the API. I have flutter_html: ^3.0.0-beta.2 version and it doesn't have useRichText function, what should I do?

I have tried other HTML packages but to no avail.